# Run Powershell.exe from command line (cmd.exe) with -Command and -File switches?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a simple module called `MyModule.psm1` defined as

```
function Show-Text($p)
{
    Write-Host $p
}

Export-ModuleMember Show-Text
```

Module is saved here -  (*All works fine, the normal way via ISE or direct Powershell command line*)

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MyModule (because 64-bit OS)
```

Now, I have a script called `Test.ps1` like this

```
Show-Text "Hello World"
```

**NB: I do not want to do Import-Module MyModule in the ps1 file**

I am running following command from a cmd.exe window

```
C:\>Powershell -Command "& {Import-Module MyModule}" -File "C:\temp\Test.ps1"
```

I get the following error

> Import-Module : The specified module 'MyModule' was not loaded because
>   no valid  module file was found in any module directory. At line:1
>   char:17
>   + & {Import-Module <<<<  MyModule} -File Show.ps1
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (MyModule:String) [Import-M    odule], FileNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
>   ands.ImportModuleCommand

*Can somebody help me how to execute `exactly what I have stated` above via **cmd.exe ONLY** without hard-coding or specifying the full Module Path please ?*

Something on the similar lines we do for loading SystemModules - `powershell.exe -ImportSystemModules`

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit cmd.exe?  If so, then the import-module should work.

Comment: Sleepy eyes needed a fresh pair of eyes to point out the mistake. Thanks Keith. If you make it as an answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running a 32-bit cmd.exe? If so then the Import-Module should work.  If you are running a 64-bit cmd.exe, that will launch a 64-bit PowerShell.exe unless you fully qualify the path to the 32-bit version of PowerShell.exe (c:\windows\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe).

Answer (score 3):

You do understand that `SysWOW64` is 32-bit and `System32` is 64-bit right?

The module is present in the 32-bit Powershell module lookup path, and hence will be seen only by the 32-bit Powershell console. If you call powershell from a 64-bit `cmd` console, you will open the 64-bit one.

Either open a 32bit cmd prompt or move it to the 64-bit modules path,