# Use Powershell to pause spotify and play audio with Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, spotify

I've managed to play a sound through powershell with the task scheduler. Now I would like to  stop all other audio before playing mine. (Mostly spotify, so that's what I'm focusing on.) I tried to use the PSSpotify module and that works like a charm when executed from within powershell, but when I fire it from "Run" it only plays my audio. It doesn't stop the music in spotify. I could just kill the spotify process, but I'd prefer some other way around.

My script:

```
if (Get-Process -Name spotify) {Invoke-Spotify -stop; Start-Sleep -s 1;}
(New-Object Media.SoundPlayer "Z:\Emil\lunch.wav").Play(); Start-Sleep -s 5; Exit;
```

What I type in Run and Task Scheduler:

```
powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -File "Z:\Emil\lunchen.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to import the PSSpotify module explicitly.  You can either add it to your ps1 file or do it in your command line.

[Run Powershell.exe from command line (cmd.exe) with -Command and -File switches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866744/run-powershell-exe-from-command-line-cmd-exe-with-command-and-file-switches) shows you can do:

```
C:\>Powershell -Command "& {Import-Module PSSpotify}" -File "Z:\Emil\lunchen.ps1"
```

Or putting the `Import-Module PSSpotify` call at the top of your script should do it too.